# Email trigger in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to trigger email notification on any table changes in bigquery. I would like to copy that table in google sheet and attached it with the email.There is scheduled query for this table which runs at 5pm everyday. Triggering will occur only when the table changes. My table look like this.Can you please assist?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do that.
Here is one work around that I can think of:

1. Create a new Pub/Sub topic to set as the sink for the Stack driver export.
2. Setup a Stack driver Logging Export, in which we define a filter to monitor BigQuery logs and fire-up when there is an update in BigQuery Table
3. Create a new Cloud Function and choose the trigger to be the Pub/Sub topic we created in Step #2.
4. Write a Python code for the Cloud Function to run these queries and save the results to GCS
5. You can create another Cloud Function trigger to mail the file whenever if arrives to GCS.
6. Alternatively, If your process is not a long running (completes within 9 mins) then you can implement your mailing logic in step #4